# Add new attribute to core data entity

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on project on Xcode7, Swift2 i made some entity but now i need to add new attribute to this entity.

if any one can help me, or give a helpful links
thanks.

Comment: If the app is already live and being used, you should look at versioning your db schema for a smooth migration of existing users and data. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Comment: add the attribute in your xcdatamodeld, regenerate the entity file, and delete the previous installation from your simulator or testing device in order to load the new schema without migrating it

Comment: thanks @markedwardmurray ,,  its work